# Retrofit Query Annotation Without Ampersand

Tags: android, rest, retrofit, okhttp, retrofit2

I am trying to make an API call to a mobile backend with Retrofit 2.0. In my API call, i have to make necessary call to this URL

> https://api.backendless.com/v1/data/Users?where=followings.objectId=%270B3BA7F9-260F-B378-FF9A-3C2448B8A700%27

To form this URL in Retrofit i have been using below interface

```
@GET("Users?where=")
Call<List<User>> getFollowers(@Query("followings.objectId") String objectId);
```

This interface call puts an ampersand before the query parameters and generates a URL like below

> https://api.backendless.com/v1/data/Users?where=&followings.objectId=%270B3BA7F9-260F-B378-FF9A-3C2448B8A700%27

I tried to overcome this with Path annotation but i keep getting "URL query string must not have replace block. For dynamic query parameters using @Query" error.

API that i am trying to connect requires a "where=" clause for filtering by design. I have no permission to change that. What i want is somehow tell Retrofit not to put an ampersand sign before the query parameter or any workarounds for this issue.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For those who seek for similar answers, I came up with below solution

I declared my interface with @Url

```
@GET
Call<List<User>> getFollowers(@Url String objectId);
```

and generated related URL part as an extension method

```
public String toFollowerRequest(){
    return RestGlobals.BASE_URL + "Users?where=followings.objectId=%27" + objectId + "%27";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@GET("{path}")
Call> getFollowers(@Path("path") path, @Query("followings.objectId") String objectId);

getFollowers("Users?where=", ...)

Comment: your proposed solution unfortunately gives me a different URL https://api.backendless.com/v1/data/Users%3Fwhere=?followings.objectId=%270B3BA7F9-260F-B378-FF9A-3C2448B8A700%27 This is because question mark right after "Users" becomes url encoded. I tried encoded=true at path annotation, but it still translates it into URL encoded