# Retrofit queries without ampersand

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I'm trying to send requests to an API that uses **semicolon(;)** instead of **ampersand(&)** for query parameters, The url request looks like this:

```
http://api.example.com/path/?param1=p1;param2=p2
```

The most similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38092895/retrofit-query-annotation-without-ampersand) I found on the internet suggests to use another method that puts url parts together and then use `@Url` annotation.

Does retrofit contain any solution for these cases ?

Thanks.

Comment: Huh? Sounds like your API is very, very broken. Are you sure that they aren't just matrix parameters?

Comment: @chrylis Honestly I have no idea!

Comment: It seems there is already an issue related to my problem : https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/450

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use an `Interceptor` to rewrite the URL from using '&' to ';'. The tricky part is doing it in a way that does not make the URL invalid.

```
new Interceptor() {
    Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        HttpUrl originalUrl = chain.request().url();
        String query = originalUrl.encodedQuery();
        if (query == null) {
            return chain.proceed(chain.request());
        } else {
            Request.Builder builder = chain.request().newBuilder();
            builder.url(originalUrl.newBuilder()
                .encodedQuery(query.replace('&', ';'))
                .build());
            return chain.proceed(builder.build());
        }
    }
};
```

This OkHttp (the networking library that powers Retrofit) Interceptor will check if the given URL has a query and replace any '&' in the query section with a ';'. In theory this should behave as you specified.

It can be applied by creating the `OkHttpClient` instance yourself and installing the abovementioned `Interceptor` while building it.